# BooleanToVisibilityConverter not working, but TextBlock verifies it should be. What could be wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I cannot get the following code to work. Please notice the TextBlock is verifying that the propertychanged event is triggering and updating as expected. The TextBlock updates to False as it should, but for some reason the local:AccountListControl does not go invisible. Any ideas?

Xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
  <local:AccountListControl DataContext="{Binding AccountListVm}" 
      Visibility="{Binding AreAccountsVisible,
      Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding AreAccountsVisible}"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public class Page : Notifiable
{
    CoaWorkspace _ws;
    public Page(CoaWorkspace ws)
    {
        _ws = ws;
        ws.Model.Stash.PropertyChanged += PropertyChangedHandler;
        (ws.Model.Stash.Selected as ICoaPackage)
            .PropertyChanged += PropertyChangedHandler;
    }
    public IAccountListVm AccountListVm
    {
        get { return _AccountListVm; }
        protected set { SetField(ref _AccountListVm, value); }
    }
    private IAccountListVm _AccountListVm = null;

    public bool AreAccountsVisible
    {
        get { return _ws.Model.Stash.Selected.Id > 0; }
    }

    private void PropertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Selected" ||
            e.PropertyName == "Id") 
                this.OnPropertyChanged("AreAccountsVisible"); 
    }
}
```

UPDATE

I added the following xaml and confirmed the converter and the bindings are working properly.

```
<TextBlock Text="TEST TEXT" Visibility="{Binding AreAccountsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

So it must have something to do with the local:AccountsListControl UserControl. I would still be interested to know why this is causing a problem.

Comment: Where are your static resources defined? My guess is that `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` doesn't exist.

Comment: I doubled check the spelling. It is definitely there. I edited the question to show this fact.

Comment: Can you show your Converter? Just to rule out the possibility that you somehow switched Visibility values..

Comment: I am using the baked in BooleanToVisibilityConverter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You have a DataContext issue.  The local:AccountList control has a different binding context than the TextBlock

Comment: @SteveMitcham Ah! So the Visibility property is trying to read from the AccountsListVm? I wouldn't have expected this.

Comment: yes.  it may be easier for you to wrap the accountVM in an invisible border and map the visibility to that instead.  I'll write up an answer, but your solution may vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DataContext is pointed at the wrong level of your model.  Here's a possible solution

```
<Grid>
  <Border Visibility="{Binding AreAccoutsVisible,
      Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
  <local:AccountListControl DataContext="{Binding AccountListVm}"/>
  </Border>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding AreAccountsVisible}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You are missing a `>` by you border.